# Android: Count number of cases in switch statement, know when last case

Tags: android, switch-statement, counting

I am busy working on an app with multiple switch statement that each have a different number of cases.

```
switch(variable){
case: 0
//do something
case: 1
//do something
case: 3
//do something
```

I can iterate through the cases by using variable = variable +1. That works fine. My problem is being able to tell when the last case in the switch statement has been reached so that I can perform a different action.

How do I know when the count is at the last case? What is the code for that?

I appreciate your time.

Comment: What do you mean  with "last case"?

Comment: Can't you just add your action on the last case?

Comment: @tm13 when i say last case i mean, using the example above, case: 3. it could be another number in another switch statement.

Comment: @josh_gom3z in the last case a button will show that will offer the user the option to do something else. I could add it to the last case but I would have to go through each switch statement and there are a lot so I am trying to find a way to count the cases in a given switch statement in order to be able to tell when the last case for a particular switch statement has been reached.

Comment: @Stark could you share your code so that we have clear understanding about your problem? Actually, you can use default case

Comment: @tm13 thank you yeah the code is basically the switch statement i am just trying to figure out out to be able to iterate through the cases with my variable = variable +1 which works but also I want the code to be able to tell when the last case for a particular switch statement has been reached without having to manually populate the default or last case in each switch.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are working inside a method or cycle
In that case you can restart the variable when it reaches the last value inside your switch

```
.
.
.
switch(variable){
    case 0:
        //do something
    case 1:
        //do something
    case 2: //this is the last 
        .
        .
        .
        //do something
        .
        .
        .
        variable = 0;
}//End of switch
.
.
.
```

**[EDIT]**

You can restart the variable in the last case of your switch.

Comment: Thanks Mijael. I am trying to get the code itself to know when the number 3 has been reached without me having to type if(variable ==3).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `default` case for your problem.

```
switch(variable){
case: 0
    //do something
    break;
case: 1
    //do something
    break;
case: 3
    //do something
    break;
default:
    // Here you can run your different action
    break;
}
```

You have to also define the max value for your **variable** so that when your **variable** value reaches to that max value it stops incrementing the **variable** value.

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I am trying to get the code itself to know when the number 3 has been reached without me having to manually type into the default case of each switch statement.